# how to get a sorted result from mysql query?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, execution-plan

I am trying to get a sorted result from a MySQL query and I don't have any idea of making the query.

I have a example MySQL table as follows :

```
 id | cat_type
 1  |  free
 2  |  free
 3  |  free
 4  |  free
 5  |  paid
 6  |  paid
... |  ...
... |  ...
... |  ...
   and it goes on.
```

The result should be as follows from the above table :

```
 id | cat_type
 1  | free 
 2  | free 
 5  | paid

 3  | free 
 4  | free 
 6  | paid

... | free
... | free
... | paid
  and goes on(should be sorted)
```

The total result should be split as 3. In the first three result, first two should be `free` and the next one should be `paid` likewise all the remaining result should be sorted as two `free` and one `paid`.

The most important is that it should be sorted as two `free` and one `paid`.

Any idea how to accomplish this using a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this from the command line/phpmyadmin:

Assuming the following table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+----------+
| id | cat_type |
+----+----------+
|  1 | free     |
|  2 | free     |
|  3 | free     |
|  4 | free     |
|  5 | paid     |
|  6 | paid     |
+----+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Make your custom ordering by selecting twice the table and using a variable as a counter:

```
mysql> SET @i := 0; 
SET @j := 0.5; 
SELECT id, cat_type FROM 
(SELECT @i := @i + 1 as ordering, id, cat_type FROM test WHERE cat_type = 'free' 
 UNION 
 SELECT @j := @j + 2 as ordering, id, cat_type FROM test WHERE cat_type = 'paid') 
AS base_table 
ORDER BY ordering;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----+----------+
| id | cat_type |
+----+----------+
|  1 | free     |
|  2 | free     |
|  5 | paid     |
|  3 | free     |
|  4 | free     |
|  6 | paid     |
+----+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is technically incorrect, as it could explore the original tables not in id order, but assuming you are using InnoDB, a full table scan in index order should be performed.

Also, this is terribly unoptimized:

```
+----+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
| id | select_type       | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY           | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   12 | Using filesort  |
|  2 | DERIVED           | test       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where     |
|  3 | UNCACHEABLE UNION | test       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where     |
| NULL | UNION RESULT      | <union2,3> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Using temporary |
+----+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To the point that if you wanted to do this in a large table, doing it programatically or using cursors would be a better idea.

Comment: what tool did you use for this ? @jynus

Comment: I am not sure what part you are referring to, but I just used the mysql command line, which is my interactive mysql client of preference, but it should work in any MySQL client, just copy the part between the `"mysql>"` and the ending `";"` and change test to your table's name.

Comment: its working great. but i just wanted to know what tool did u used. thanks.

Comment: For creating the query, I used the tool "mysql" it is a GPL text-based client for MySQL that comes builtin with the server. You can know more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html and download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ For writing the query, I did it manually by hand, without any other tool, for the "optimization analysis", I just run `EXPLAIN` before the SELECT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

Comment: thnq.... @jynus